# Caching Techniques for Mobile and Desktop Pages When Using Akamai

Tags: asp.net-mvc, akamai

We have a ASP.NET MVC website which uses Akamai for caching. The requests are cached on Akamai server and the subsequent requests are returned from the cache instead of the ASP.NET MVC pipeline.

Now, we are introducing the mobile views using the (ActionName.Mobile.chtml) syntax in ASP.NET MVC. The mobile views are part of the original app with the .Mobile keyword added in them. We are concerned that since mobile pages will be served by the same controller action calls that we will get mobile pages for our desktop pages and vice versa.

Does anyone have any experience in Akamai caching behavior in terms of when used with desktop webpages and mobile webpages?

Comment: I'm going to be facing the same problem very soon with our MVC website. Was Akamai able to serve the correct views?